# One wireless connection will not work - claims security settings do not match

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

at work there is one wireless connection that seems to have given up the ghost in recognising this computer. It was intermittent before, connecting but often not getting internet access, requiring disconnection and re-connection. Now it appears it just doesn't work and often claims that security settings don't match.

This is not the case, as the password and type of security hasn't changed. If I plug in via LAN cord it nearly always works and there is no security mismatch.

The computer doesn't have a problem with wifi at home or elsewhere and others (and my phone) find the problematic wifi connection fine.

Is there a reason for it getting the knickers in a knot? It is a pain to be tied to the desk.

I did some playing with DNS settings etc, but I don't know enough to diagnose really.

Thanks,

N

Comment: refresh that connection, on your wifi networks manager, go to that network definitions, delete all data regarding to that network, discover it again and log-in, maybe the security protocol has changed from some reason..

Comment: Thanks and good suggestion. I tried this, but no network connectivity. Trouble shooter now says 'Problem with wireless adapter or access point'. Wifi adapter is enabled, but I do get a bit of on and off with the Intel 'My Wifi' adapter somehow as it seems to be disabled at times, but it is on now.